# Spring JUnit test runner @ContextConfiguration just loading a single file

Tags: java, spring, junit

I'm loading a spring bean from a test class using the bean factory

```
XmlBeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(new ClassPathResource("my-bean-file.xml"))
MyBean bean = (MyBean) factory.getBean("myBean")
```

Can I use the Spring JUnit4TestRunner to load individual beans or is that only used to load an entire application context?

Comment: You could declare a file with a single bean in :)

Comment: If I want to use my actual spring context files though, that isn't really practical...

Comment: Yeah, that's not really a sensible option. I don't think you can avoid loading a full application context with the test runner.

Comment: Ah well, bean factory it is then. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will load the entire application context. But you can split up your bean files (e.g. into DAOs, service layer, controllers), and in your main app include each file once. In your test, just use the layer you're interested in.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this because your beans are too expensive to be all loaded, you could declare them lazy, meaning they will only be loaded when needed.

Spring Documentation sample:

```
<bean id="lazy" class="com.foo.ExpensiveToCreateBean" lazy-init="true"/>

<bean name="not.lazy" class="com.foo.AnotherBean"/>
```

> However, when a lazy-initialized bean is a dependency of a singleton
>   bean that is not lazy-initialized, the ApplicationContext creates the
>   lazy-initialized bean at startup, because it must satisfy the
>   singleton's dependencies. The lazy-initialized bean is injected into a
>   singleton bean elsewhere that is not lazy-initialized.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lazy-init

Comment: Thanks. I'll consider doing that, though I need to see how it affects the rest of the app.